# Puppeteer "Unable to move ShaderCache" when attempting to load Chrome profile

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I've had quite a few issues trying to get Puppeteer to run in an existing chrome window with user data. I've tried simplifying things down and here is my current code. I don't know what else to do as i've tried everything related to the issue:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data'
})
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

This causes the following error:

```
error Error: Failed to launch chrome!
[8084:14860:0321/091939.752:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(19)] Unable to move the cach
e: 0
[8084:14860:0321/091939.752:ERROR:cache_util.cc(140)] Unable to move cache folde
r C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\GPUCache
 to C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ShaderCache\old_GP
UCache_000
[8084:14860:0321/091939.752:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[8084:14860:0321/091939.752:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(622)] Shader Cache Creati
on failed: -2
```

Comment: try to copy also `Executable Path` from `chrome://version` along with `Profile Path`, so you should get something like: 
  `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User ',
})
const page = await browser.newPage();`

Comment: You should've updated your old question with this code, this feels so specific and useful :D

Comment: Tried this with the executable path and the specific profile directory rather than the user directory, same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to an open Chrome process. Make sure you close all of them in the task manager and the following will work:

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    executablePath: `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe`,
    userDataDir: `C:\\Users\\Marwan\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data`,
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep the already open window open, and thus not closing it?